# Cloning item with image, image takes time to appear

Tags: jquery, clone

I am trying to clone an item with jQuery and then animate it.
The original item has an image in it which is already loaded and shown prior to the cloning.
However, in the cloned item, the image only shows about half way through the animation.

Here is the html of the item to clone:

```
<div class='item'>
     <div class='picture'><img src='img/picture1.jpg'></div>
     <h3>Item</h3>
     <p class='price'>$25</p>
     <div class='desc'>Image description...</div>
 </div>
```

And the jQuery I'm using to clone it:

```
itemObject = $(".item"); // Code has proper selector to choose appropriate item
newItemObject = itemObject.clone()

// Overlay new object over original object
newItemObject.appendTo('#main').css({
    'position': 'absolute',
    'top': itemObject.offset().top,
    'left': itemObject.offset().left
});

// Do animation on newItemObject...
```

Is this something that always occurs when cloning elements with images in? Is there something wrong with what I'm doing? How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you verified that the headers for the image allow the browser to cache it?

Comment: Don't double wrap, this will work fine as well: `newItemObject = itemObject.clone()` however it doesn't explain the problem - how exactly you animate?

Comment: @JonasH Thanks! I was generating images with PHP and didn't cache anything. Fixed that and it works fine now!

Comment: Make a copy of div and use 'display:none;' for that div. when animation is needed, change display css property and start animation.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Fixed, what exactly is the difference?

Comment: The `$(something_in_here)` is wrapping `something_in_here` as jQuery object. As `itemObject` is already jQuery object, you don't have to wrap it again. While not an error, it's just meaningless that's all. For the record, looks like the animation requested the image every time, so as it wasn't cached it explains why it was so slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verify that the headers for the image allow the browser to cache it. (Thanks [Jonas H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85215/jonas-h))

(The images were being served from a PHP file that didn't cache them, therefore they were reloaded when cloned.)